# how to tell ember-cli to build using another file other than app/index.html

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there a way to tell ember cli to use another HTML file for building instead of app/index.html? I have an in-app-addon and Im not sure how to find that information. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. If you want to configure the name of the `index.html` check the documentation at http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#configuring-output-paths.

Comment: that is the output HTML file name. I want to specify the input HTML file name, which comes from app/index.html. Basically I want to tell ember cli to build using app/app.html in certain environments. If that isn't possible, is there a way to put conditional logic in app/index.html?

Answer (score 2):

I fiddled around with this for quite a while and ended up with a solution that avoids multiple `index.html` files alltogether, as I couldn't find a good way to tell ember-cli to use an index file of my choice.

I used [ember-cli-inline-content](https://github.com/gdub22/ember-cli-inline-content) to customize the content of `index.html` based on the current configuration.

You basically add `{{content-for "key1"}}` where you need environment-specific code to be inserted into the index file.

As you can read in the documentation for [ember-cli-inline-content](https://github.com/gdub22/ember-cli-inline-content), the configuration for `"key1"` goes in the `ember-cli-build.js` file.

As an aside: If you need to access your `ENV` object from `config/environment.js` you can do it like so:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var ENV = require('./config/environment')(EmberApp.env());
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Nicolai. This is what I ended up doing. :)